# Parsing SOAP response from file with JDOM

Tags: java, xml, soap, jdom

I'm trying to parse SOAP response from file.
This is out.xml

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
    <response xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <result>
    <config>...</config>
    <config>...</config>
    <config>...</config>
    </result>
    </response>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

This is code with jdom:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
try {

   Document document = builder.build( new File("out.xml"));
   Element root = document.getRootElement();
   Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("http://tempuri.org/");
   List r = root.getChildren("config", ns);
   System.out.println(r.size());

}
```

Why does this output 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDOM's `getChildren` method is documented as this (emphasis mine):

> This returns a List of all the child elements nested directly (**one level deep**) within this element, as Element objects.

See the original [here](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Element.html#getChildren%28%29).

Your call to `getRootElement` puts you onto `soap:Envelope`, which doesn't have any `config` child nodes.

To get around this, you can either:

1. call `getChildren` multiple times to navigate through the `soap:Body`, `response` and `result` elements
2. call `getDescendants` to get an iterator that **does** traverse the entire hierarchy and not just one level

Comment: Thank you. Actually I'm searching for access to particular element directly easy way. But it helped.